# Hide/Show DIv with class ? Typical one with nested Div's

Tags: jquery, html, css

I been trying for positioning functionality of my Table Tools toolbar in datatable . well i dropped the idea to do it just because its not possible i feel .

Now i have had a Div with class contained in other div . I want to show.hide the particluar div on my button Click .

My Html code :

```
<div class="table-responsive">
  <div id="myDataTable_wrapper" class="dataTables_wrapper" role="grid">
     <div class="DTTT_container ui-buttonset ui-buttonset-multi">
     //i have my datatable html here 
     </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I want to hide and show Div class with DTTT_container on click .

I tried like this :
On my initial page rendering i am making DTTT_container as hidden using

```
<style>
DTTT_container
{
visibility:hidden;
}
</style>
```

Under My button click i have to hide/show .

```
$('#btnclick').click(function()
{
//I am unable to get correct logic to hide/show i.e toggling .
});
```

Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

hide the `.DTTT_container` in the beginning using css `display:none;` to use `.toggle()`.

Try this:

```
$('#btnclick').click(function()
{
  $('div.DTTT_container ').toggle();
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You cannot use .toggle() with elements which was set with css property `visibility`

Try,

```
$('#btnclick').click(function() {

 var elem = $('.DTTT_container');
 var visibility = elem.css('visibility');

 if(visibility === "hidden") {
   elem.css('visibility','visible');
 }
 else {
     elem.css('visibility','hidden');
 }

});
```

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/cXvnJ/)

---

or you can do some tricks by using .toggleClass() like below,

CSS:

```
.visible {
    visibility :visible;
}
.hidden {
    visibility :hidden;
}
```

JS:

```
$('#btnclick').click(function () {
    $('.DTTT_container').toggleClass('visible hidden');
});
```

### [DEMO I](http://jsfiddle.net/cXvnJ/1/)

Comment: Out of the 5 answers, this one seems like the best to suit your needs.

Answer (score 1):

Change your css to:

```
.DTTT_container
{
    display: none;
}
```

then you can use **[.toggle()](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/)**:

```
$('#btnclick').click(function() {
    $('.DTTT_container').toggle()
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Your css code is not hide any element.. You are using visible property

```
$('#btnclick').click(function()
{


$(".DTTT_container").css("visibility","visible");
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking for

```
$('.DTTT_container').toggle();
```

Refer here for more: http://api.jquery.com/toggle/